# After Spring Data ES migration : IllegalArgumentException: NamedWriteable is already registered for [...], cannot register [...]

Tags: maven, spring-boot, migration, elasticsearch-5, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a spring application (that's part of spring discovery cluster as discovery client). We have chosen to migrate this app from spring data elasticsearch 2.1.1.RELEASE (link to a dockerise 2.4.3-alpine elasticsearch) to SDE 3.0.14.RELEASE (that can be linked, if i'm correct, with a dockerise ES 5.5.0-alpine). My problem is that this app never achieve to start.

NOTE: It was perfectly working before the migration

First, I thought it was a trouble with maven dependencies, so I tried to find duplicate dependancies but I didn't have result.
I also tried to use a own TransportClient (with erasing app properties to prevent spring autoconfiguration), like Elasticsearch documentation describes (but apparently, spring should be able to do it itself).

Here's main class (with some, maybe useful, spring annotations):

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableFeignClients
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = {"com.sap.testreportservice"}, repositoryBaseClass = ApplicationRepositoryImpl.class)
public class TestreportServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestreportServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here's its maven dependancies:

```xml
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zuul</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.14.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20190722</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Here's some app properties:

```
spring:
  data:
    elasticsearch:
      cluster-name: ${ES_CLUSTER_NAME:insights}
      cluster-nodes: ${ES_CLUSTER_NODES:localhost:9300}
```

Here's my custom Transport Client:

```java
@Configuration
public class ElasticsearchConfig {

    @Bean
    Client client() {
        Settings settings = Settings.builder()
                .put("cluster.name", "insights")
                .build();
        TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings);
        try {
            client.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return client;
    }
}
```

Here's some log extract (ask me for the complete stacktrace)

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: NamedWriteable [org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilder][parent_id] is already registered for [org.elasticsearch.search.SearchModule$$Lambda$942/734191650], cannot register [org.elasticsearch.join.ParentJoinPlugin$$Lambda$952/956934228]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.NamedWriteableRegistry.<init>(NamedWriteableRegistry.java:91) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.buildTemplate(TransportClient.java:148) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.<init>(TransportClient.java:254) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.TransportClientFactoryBean$SpringDataTransportClient.<init>(TransportClientFactoryBean.java:234) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.TransportClientFactoryBean.buildClient(TransportClientFactoryBean.java:103) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.TransportClientFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(TransportClientFactoryBean.java:98) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.elasticsearchClient(ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.java:59) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$151bff6d.CGLIB$elasticsearchClient$0(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$151bff6d$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$575694c9.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$151bff6d.elasticsearchClient(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 145 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

These are pretty old versions to which you are upgrading.

Looking at the stacktrace you see that Spring Boot is still automatically creating the `TransportClient`, if you want to provide your bean, you should change your code to:

```
@Bean
TransportClient elasticsearchClient() {
    Settings settings = Settings.builder()
            .put("cluster.name", "insights")
            .build();
    TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings);
    try {
        client.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return client;
}
```

Spring Boot autoconfiguration has a `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` annotation on it's factory method, and that checks for `TransportClient`, not `Client`. With this you will provide the `TransportClient`, but Spring Boot will do the rest of the autoconfiguration.

To disable autoconfiguration for Elasticsearch you can use `@SpringBootApplication(exclude={ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.class})`.

Do you have elasticsearch plugin configuration somewhere in your config? Because the error you see comes from the fact, that the Client that the autoconfiguration tries to build wants to register the `ParentJoinPlugin`(that's hardcoded in the `TransportClientFactoryBean` of that version and there is already a conflicting entry registered.